# how to change color of combo box which should appear by default on the combo box box in which toggle button is located?

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
This is my code to change the color of combo box box in which toggle button is located-
<Window.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="GrayColor_">#FF928B81</Color>
        <Color x:Key="LightGrayColor_">#FFC3C3C3</Color>
        <Color x:Key="LightLightGrayColor_">#FFF1F1F1</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayColor" Color="{StaticResource GrayColor_}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGrayColor" Color="{StaticResource LightGrayColor_}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightLightGrayColor" Color="{StaticResource LightLightGrayColor_}"/>

        <Color x:Key="BlueColor_">#0073b0</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DarkBlueColor_">#FF004165</Color>
        <Color x:Key="LightBlueColor_">#FFa4ddfa</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueColor" Color="{StaticResource BlueColor_}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBlueColor" Color="{StaticResource DarkBlueColor_}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBlueColor" Color="{StaticResource LightBlueColor_}" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foreground" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundWhite" Color="White"/>


        <Style x:Key="LightGrayBox" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}" />
        </Style>


        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Style="{DynamicResource LightGrayBox}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.6" Fill="{StaticResource GrayColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonActive" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{DynamicResource BlueColor}" />
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="StandardComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" ClickMode="Press"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            <Label Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                               ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <!--<ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />-->
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                                 CaretBrush="{DynamicResource ForegroundWhite}"
                                 Style="{x:Null}" 
                                 Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                 Margin="3,3,23,3" 
                                 Focusable="True" 
                                 Background="Transparent" 
                                 Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundWhite}" 
                                 Visibility="Hidden"
                                 IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup VerticalOffset="-1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                                <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="200">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Style="{DynamicResource LightGrayBox}"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="ToggleButton" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonActive}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundWhite}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Foreground}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

                </Style>

            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="122,32,100,0" Style="{StaticResource StandardComboBox}"  Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEditable="True" Text="Hello">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="2"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="3"></ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

The problem is the changed color is getting displayed on click of toggle button,but I want the changed color should appear by default on the combo box box in which toggle button is there? Iahve tried many things which are already there in my code,please suggest what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Border Background in the Style - `ComboBoxToggleButton`

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
               ...
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Style="{DynamicResource LightGrayBox}"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{StaticResource BlueColor}"/>
               ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```